# do not seem to run the jobtracker or namenode

Tags: hadoop

when running the jps command, the jobtracker and namenode should be shown at the same time?
(not be shown namenode or jobtracker)

why does not run the jobtracker?

and..
Sometimes the job tracker is running, do not run the namenode.

Comment: Please, provide some more info, like the commands you used to start the jobtracker and namenode and also check their respective logs for errors

Comment: the command that i use for running is 'start-all.sh'.                   
when i check the log file of namenode(hadoop-hadoop-namenode-user.log) 

error message:
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Unable to move
last checkpoint for /home/hadoop/hadoop-dta/dfs/name
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete /home/hadoop/hadoop-data/dfs/name/
previous.checkpoint

Comment: oh! i solve it! It was a problem of access-permission to the folder. i got a hint ! you say "check their respective logs for errors"  Thank you!